# What are the constraints on replacements of the phrase "Holy S—t"?

Tags: slang, offensive-language

When my friend found out that the new season of Rick and Morty is going to be released this year, he yelled in excitement:

> Holy fucking **Rick**!

This is not a valid (ie. grammatically correct) replacement for the phrase "[Holy Shit](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/holy+shit)."

It made me think:

> What words could replace "shit" in this slang, without changing its meaning?

For example, I know that we can use these:

- [Holy Fuck](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=holy%20fuck)

  > An exclamation, much like "**Holy Shit**!", but more offensive, which is good.
- [Holy Moly](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=holy%20moly)

  > a term often used instead of and meaning "**holy shit**" either by a young person in front of *their parents to avoid getting an ass whooping or by a young person in front of peers as a term of surprise, shock.

Now, "fuck" and "moly" are both nouns here. But we can't use every other noun as a replacement for the word "shit" to indicate *surprise!*

So my question is, given a phrase like this, how can I validate it to see if it's a correct replacement of "holy shit"? What words are acceptable here? How I can prove to my friend that what he said doesn't make sense?

Comment: What's wrong with "Holy fucking Rick"? People say ["Holy fucking Jesus"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Holy%20Fucking%20Jesus) all the time.

Comment: @Laurel I think that's because "Jesus" alone can indicate surprise, but "Rick" doesn't.

Comment: What does "*~~~~~*" mean in your first example? Is that a slot to fill?

Comment: @Mitch It's a modified version of this `(*_*)` emoticon (meaning  or *Amazed.*) It's useless information, but since I was quoting, I thought I include it.

Comment: @AmirAShabani I don't even recognize the unmodified one. There's already punctuation that everyone knows that accounts for that emotion, the exclamation point.

Comment: @Mitch fair enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no problem with "holy fucking Rick". Really, *any* noun or noun phrase can be used in this expression. It's a [snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone).

["Holy astringent plum-like fruit!"](https://www.66batmania.com/trivia/robins-holy/) Robin in the 1960s Batman TV show always had some crazy variation on the phrase. It's so iconic that Robin has continued to say lines like these ever since. (See [this video](https://youtu.be/85LUuF6ZXaU) of clips from *The New Adventures of Batman* for example.)

You'll see similar elsewhere, even when it's not a parody of campy Robin. For example, here are some examples from Google Books:

- > HOLY FUCKING HIGH DRUID! —[Of Bone and Thunder: A Novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=KtS5BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&dq="holy+fucking"+)
- > Holy fucking shark week! —[Imperfectly Criminal](https://books.google.com/books?id=oOtYBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT135&dq="holy+fucking"+)
- > Holy fucking—Goat! —[Blood on the Bayou](https://books.google.com/books?id=m86-vs0mchYC&pg=PT297&dq="holy+fucking"+)
- > Holy fucking Kraken. —[Kraken: An Anatomy](https://books.google.com/books?id=LvuziReWM7MC&pg=PA350&dq="holy+fucking"+)
- > *Holy fucking boom dogs, mon.* —[Blackmail Earth](https://books.google.com/books?id=SKZIxoZBnfkC&pg=PT115&dq="holy+fucking"+)

See also [the Wikipedia page for this expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Holy...%22).

Comment: +1 for the Robin link alone.

Comment: I see, thank you. BTW, the video was hard but fun to watch.